# Proper way to read ELF files in C

Tags: c, elf, fread

first time posting here, Googled for a few hours and I couldn't find anything.

I am trying to write a client program that reads different files and sends them over the web to a server program. (For backup purposes.)

So far I have used fread() to put the files into a buffer, in a way that is similar to this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/

It works fine for plain-text files, but when I try to transfer executable files, fread() doesn't seem to read the files, only reading "ELF" into the buffer.

My question is, what is the proper way to read the contents of an ELF file into a buffer in C?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. An ELF file should be no different than any other file. Could you post some code?

Comment: Sounds like you've opened the file in text mode instead of binary.

Comment: Perhaps some sample code of how your application reads files? There is no "tips and tricks" to binary files using normal file I/O (except that reading the entire file into memory is usually unjustified).

Comment: The OP didn't specify that it was Unix.

Comment: you're probably reading it in fine, but I'll bet you're using string operations on the result. string operations always quit when they see a null.

Comment: Have you tried LibElf? http://wiki.freebsd.org/LibElf, http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html

Comment: @cnicutar Yeah, I hadn't twigged on the unix part (elf files implies it even if it's not stated), but fread certainly does stop mid stream on Windows if you open in text mode and try to read a byte with value 0x1A.

Comment: @tinman Crazy stuff. I deleted my comments since I am no longer interested in the question. Still, got some documentation on that ?

Comment: @cnicutar It's hinted at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and described on forums such as http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t282808-fread-perform-differently-from-window-to-linux.html but it's easy enough to test. I've never seen it explicity stated anywhere, just been bitten by it enough times.

Comment: Pro tip: for sending files over the network, use [`sendfile(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) on *nix systems and [`TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.  They're much more efficient than a `read(2)/send(2)` or `ReadFile/WriteFile` loop.

Comment: Thank you jcomeau_ictx, that was the issue, kind of embarrassing actually.

Comment: Thanks Adam Rosenfield, this looks great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to read binary files is simply to use `fread()`.  But remember that you cannot treat the contents as a string, which means (among other things) you cannot use `strlen()` to determine their length.

Instead, you must keep the length in a seperate variable.  The return value of `fread()` will tell you how many records it successfully read - if you set the record size to 1 (the second parameter to `fread()`) then it will return the number of bytes read.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to process ELF files is with the ELF library (`libelf`; Google knows about it), assuming that it is available to you.  An ELF file has an elaborate structure and the library will usually make it easier to handle the files.

If you must use `fread()`, then it will work fine as long as you recognize that the data is full of null or zero bytes and that ordinary string functions will not process the data accurately because of the zeroes in the data.  In particular, functions like `printf()` stop printing a string at the first zero byte.

For backing up arbitrary files over a network, you simply need to open the file (in binary mode; it does no harm on Unix and is crucial on Windows), and read large blocks into memory and write them out again:

```
/* Copy the rest of f1 to f2 */
void fcopy(FILE *f1, FILE *f2)
{
    char            buffer[BUFSIZ];
    size_t          n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f1)) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, f2) != n)
            err_syserr("write failed\n");
    }
}
```

The `err_syserr()` function is a simple error reporting function that reports the error given in its argument(s) and adds the system error message (`strerror(errno)`) and exits.